# Apps crashing after force shutdown

Tags: iphone

Do all apps crash if you load them in the simulator - hit the home key to take you out of the app - double click the home key to bring up the multitasker - hold down the app you just loaded to force close it - and then try to open it again through the screen on the simulator?  My app keeps doing this so i loaded a stable app (an exercise from a book) and it did the same thing.  Is this because of how the simulator operates or the app itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the application I am currently working on does not crash in that situation.  I would suggest working on this through the debugger and tracking it down.

Comment: I figured it out - it was something that new xcode 4 beta was doing - it doesnt do that in xcode 3